# Vertical scrolling is not visible for ng-repeat in angular view

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am getting list of customers from backend. I want to populate from it into ng-repeat. If we have more customers, vertical scroll should be visible but it not visible, Why It is not visible.?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="hike.css">
<div ng-show='isLoading' class="row">
  <div class="col-mg-12 hike-container">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="hike table table-hover tab-panel tab-content">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                    <span>Customer Id</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <span>Email</span>
                </th>             
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                  <td>{{customer.id}}</td>

                  <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
                  </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**hike.css**

```
div.lhike-container .lhike{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
    border-color: #dde6e9;
}
th {
    background: rgba(102, 123, 147, 0.14);
    text-align: center;
}
tbody > tr.odd{
    background: #FAFBFC;
}
tbody > tr > td {
  text-align: center;
  height: 52px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Controller

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('CustController', CustController);
    CustController.$inject = ['$scope', 'customerService'];
    function CustController($scope, customerService,){


      $scope.isLoading = false;

      customerService.getCustomers.then(function(response){
        if(response.data.error === 0){
          if(response.data.result.customers){
            $scope.customers = response.data.result.customers;
          }
        }
        $scope.isLoading = true;
      });
    }
})();
```

Comment: Can you add the controller code as well

Comment: @Srijith Add controller...

Answer (score 0):

Check this snippet. I had to mock your `CustomerService` but the scrolling works fine for me. I am using Chrome to test this. Couple of issues that I noticed in your html is that you are using `col-mg-12` from bootstrap? That should be `col-md-12`.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('CustController', CustController);
  CustController.$inject = ['$scope'];

  function CustController($scope) {
    $scope.isLoading = false;
    $scope.customers = [{
      id: '1',
      email: '1@1.com'
    }, {
      id: '2',
      email: '2@1.com'
    }, {
      id: '3',
      email: '3@1.com'
    }, {
      id: '4',
      email: '4@1.com'
    }, {
      id: '5',
      email: '5@1.com'
    }, {
      id: '2',
      email: '2@1.com'
    }, {
      id: '3',
      email: '3@1.com'
    }, {
      id: '4',
      email: '4@1.com'
    }, {
      id: '5',
      email: '5@1.com'
    }]
  }
})();
```

```css
div.lhike-container .lhike {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 1px;
  border-color: #dde6e9;
}
th {
  background: rgba(102, 123, 147, 0.14);
  text-align: center;
}
tbody > tr.odd {
  background: #FAFBFC;
}
tbody > tr > td {
  text-align: center;
  height: 52px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="CustController">
        {{isLoading}}
    <div class="col-mg-12 hike-container">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="hike table table-hover tab-panel tab-content">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <span>Customer Id</span>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <span>Email</span>
                </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="customer in customers" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
                <td>{{customer.id}}</td>

                <td>{{customer.email}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to scroll the table, simply provide a fixed or maximum height for the parent div.

```
<style>
    .table-responsive {    
        max-height: 400px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
</style>
```